# Beta function solution for $\int_0^2(16-x^2)^{-3/2}\,dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, beta-function

$$\int_0^2(16-x^2)^{-3/2}\,dx$$
I need to solve this integral by using the beta function. So firstly I substituted $x=4t$, and my limits change to $[0,1/2]$. Then I substited $t^2=u$, $t=\sqrt u$. And my limits change again to $[0,1/4]$. Now I have
$$\int_0^{1/4}u^{1/2-1}(1-u)^{-1/2-1}\,du$$
but I need positive values of power minus one in order to get beta function. And limits should be 0 to 1. Did I made mistake somewhere or I need another substitution of $u$?

Comment: Семён: Please format your post, use mathjax.

Comment: Sorry I have no experience in mathjax, and it will take plenty of time for me learn it)

Comment: If you don't learn it then then probability of getting an answer will be very low. OK. I will edit your post. Take that as the first lesson... But check my edits.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate that. I’ll try to learn it as fast as possible

Comment: Parcly Taxel did it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may notice that the integral $$ \mathcal{J}=\int_{0}^{1/4}\sqrt{\frac{u}{1-u}}\frac{du}{u(1-u)}$$ greatly simplifies after the substitution $\frac{u}{1-u}=v$, i.e. $u=\frac{v}{1+v}$, $du=\frac{dv}{(1+v)^2}$:
$$ \mathcal{J}=\int_{0}^{1/3}\frac{dv}{\sqrt{v}}\stackrel{v=z/3}{=}\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dz}{\sqrt{z}}=\frac{B\left(1,\tfrac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{3}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}. $$

Comment: Oh, thank you, rewriting in other way helps very much.

Answer (score 1):

substitute $$x=4\sin(t)$$ then we get $$dx=4\cos(t)dt$$

Comment: I made it that way but I need to solve by using beta function.